# How to build a proxy using Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I was wondering if I could build a proxy using nginx. I only need the HTTPS traffic. Is it possible using nginx? If yes, how?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .. that said, you're probably looking for a "reverse proxy" if you're hiding or buffering a webserver behind it

Comment: @Rodrigo Check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1078484/nginx-stream-block-with-wildcard-filtering-of-subdomains) ServerFault thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: I can use `proxy_connect` of `ngx_http_proxy_connect_module`